# How to load another's service certificate to my WebLogic truststore?

Tags: certificate, weblogic, truststore

An online service provided me with their certificate (a pfx file) along with its password.

I am looking to load that into my WebLogic 8.1 truststore in Unix.

There is a truststore currently that exists in my WebLogic.

I am new to this so I was wondering what was the process to add that other party's certificate to my existing WebLogic keystore.

Do I need to convert the pfx file into a different for Unix?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the opensource GUI keytool replacement Portecle.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/portecle/

Answer (score 0):

I did [something similar](http://jonwilliams.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/configure-ssl-for-nodemanager/)--import a self-signed certificate into custom keystore on 9.x.